# How do I match code to Git commit, and create branch?

Tags: git, merge, git-extensions, git-commit

I have a git repository on my "DEV" machine. A while ago, I copied some code to my PROD machine. Since then, there have been many commits in my DEV machine. However there may have been a couple of ad-hock code changes on my PROD machine that was never committed or "Brached" out.

Question: How can I find the commit on DEV that is closest to code on PROD?

I then will create a branch and merge. The objective is to merge all into 1 branch. There are many files on PROD that have never been modified so maybe that will be easier, just search all commits for an exact match.

I use git-extensions.

ty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use `git bisect` to search over your old commits, at each step using a directory diff tool to compare the git working directory with PROD. If the working directory has new changes since PROD you want to keep, mark it `good`. If the working directory has old versions of files and you want the PROD version instead, mark it `bad`. Eventually you should find the commit that's closest to where PROD started - create a branch from there, copy over from PROD and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

With no other information (and assuming your PROD machine's install isn't a git repository itself, which would make this quite simple), I'd probably just compare file creation timestamps with your DEV repo's commit history. Presumably your PROD machine's code was copied in a narrow window. It's also likely that you weren't committing while you were doing this copy. Simply use `git log` to find the commit timestamp right before the copy timestamp, then something like:

```
git checkout -B new_branch <hash_of_that_commit>    # Checks out 'new_branch' at that commit
```

Next, diff DEV and PROD, copying PROD changes back onto DEV either incrementally or as a batch. Commit with each increment or batch.

At that point you have a viable topic branch. You can merge or rebase it back into your master branch at your leisure.